# How do I use pgadmin to interact with my data in an IBM Databases for Postgresql deployment?

Tags: database, postgresql, ibm-cloud, pgadmin

I have an [IBM Cloud Databases for PostgreSQL](https://www.ibm.com/products/databases-for-postgresql) deployment. I want to use [pgadmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) with that deployment. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in two different ways: one is to run pgadmin locally in a docker container. pgadmin has a ready-made docker container that you can use. In a terminal type:

```bash
docker run -it -p 8080:80 \                                                 
    -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@domain.com' \
    -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret' \
    -d dpage/pgadmin4
```

This runs the pgadmin in docker and makes it accessible at `http://localhost:8080`
You log in with the above credentials.
[image: Log in with above credentials]

Once logged in you will need to "Add New Server" and provide the connection details to the database, which you can get from the Resources list of your [IBM Cloud account](https://cloud.ibm.com/resources)

[image: Enter Server name]
[image: Enter IBM PG instance credentials]
[image: Set ssl mode to Allow]

The other way of deploying pgadmin is to do it in a serverless way in the cloud, using [IBM Code Engine](https://www.ibm.com/products/code-engine). The pgadmin instance will then be accessible on a public web URL. You can do that by following [this tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-for-postgresql?topic=databases-for-postgresql-pgadmin-code-engine-icd-postgresql).

Once deployed, you will need to follow similar steps to the ones described above to log in and connect to your database instance.

> Note that setting sslmode to `allow` means that although the traffic between pgadmin and PostgreSQL is encrypted, the PG service is not verified against the CA certificate provided by IBM Databases for PostgreSQL credentials.